# SEO friendly URLs for Magento

Tags: php, apache, magento, httpd.conf

I am a newbie to Magento and Apache conf. I'm using Magento 1.8.0. I have configured the path so as to remove index.php from the URLs for my pages eg 
from

> /magento/index.php/electronics/cell-phones.html

to

> /magento/electronics/cell-phones.html

However my browser requests now direct to the index.php of my server root. I have tried adding a config section for magento as shown, but no change. What am I doing wrong?

```
<Directory "C:/hiddenpath/apache2/htdocs/magento">
Options All
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from none
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess file find `Rewrite Base/` and replace it with `Rewrite Base/magento` if it is commented using `#` un comment it.